# Assign Variable concurrency nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I dont know why the function post execute before than scrapeador.
Anyone can help me?

The outpost is the following:
d9999,00
a9999,00
b2999,95
c2999,95

I dont know why the function post execute before than scrapeador.
Anyone can help me?

```
   const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://www.coolmod.com/coolpc-gamer-xvii-i9-9900k-rtx-2080-ti-11gb-16gb-ddr4-3200mhz-ssd-500gb-plus-1tb-hdd-precio';

let precioActual = '9999,00';
const request = require("request");
let url2 ="";
let mensaje = "";


async function postea(){
    //console.log(precioActual);
    console.log('d'+precioActual);
    let url2 = "https://api.telegram.org/bot829020892:AAGkxxZngee1fteQHbqu3OaOlhw5XKsmJQQ/sendMessage?chat_id=246860546&text="+precioActual;
    request.get(url2, (error, response, body) => {
    let json = JSON.parse(body);
    });
    return ;
}


async function scrapeador(){
    await rp(url).then(function(html){
        var precio = $("*[itemprop = 'price']", html).text().split('\n')[1].replace(/ /g, "").replace('€',"").replace('.',"");;
        if (precioActual > precio){
            //Almaceno el nuevo precio y doy la alerta
            console.log('a'+precioActual);
            console.log('b'+precio);
            precioActual = precio;
            console.log('c'+precioActual);
            //console.log(precio);
            //Aviso en el bot de Telegram
        }
        return;
    }).catch(function(err){
        //handle error
    });

}

scrapeador().then(postea());
```

Comment: Add `await` before `rp(url)...` in `scrapeador`. Right now the function sets up handlers for `rp(url)` then returns before any of them get executed. Also the last line should be `scrapedor().then(postea);`.

Comment: @Mason `.then()` waits for the promise to be resolved.

Comment: @Barmar `scrapedor()` resolves when it returns, and it returns before `rp(url).then(...` ever does anything because it's not being `await`ed.

Comment: @Mason `await func(); other code;` is the same as `func().then(function() { other code })`. You don't use both `await` and `.then()`.

Comment: @Barmar https://runkit.com/ursi/5d83e2ba6f0946001a8eafbc

Comment: I write await before rp(url) and still not working

Comment: @Ivan does `precio` get logged before `precioActual`?

Comment: @Mason yes precio is set before precioActual

Comment: I discover that fucntion post execute before than scrapeador and i dont know why

Comment: @Mason i rewrite and post the code here and i show the output

Comment: @Ivan look at my first comment. `postea` is called first because you have `.then(postea())` when it should be `.then(postea)`

Comment: @Mason yep it was the mistake, now works perfect thanks for all

Comment: @Waldi rather than editing to improve the question, I'd recommend to close (and eventually delete) it, it was resolved to be a typo years ago.

Comment: @Bergi, you're right, thanks - I was in a `asign` -> `assign` correction trip